# Time based hash that allows for comparison of hashed data

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

I'm trying to hash two different geo positions `(-180.0, 60.59)` and `(-179.0, 80.40)` to protect the geo positions from being known while allowing to know the number differences between the two hashes. I figured the answer would be having a key generated and stored in the client and having a time based key in the hash.

Comment: **the number differences between the two hashes**, what does this mean?

Comment: @BishalGautam I would like to be able to figure out the difference between the two geo positions by using the hash without ever finding out the geo positions. Like (-180.0)/(60.0) would be a 140 difference.

Comment: Do you mean absolute differences between lattitude and longitude of geo position. If so, **(-180.0, 60.0)** will be 240 , not 140.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cryptographic Hash functions are not preserving operations, that is;

```
a + b != H(a+b)
```

Think the + as any operation. This will be very dangerous to allow finding hash collisions.

What you need is homomorphic encryption that enables at least one operation. An example is [Paillier cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem). When you multiply the ciphertext you get the addition of the plaintext.

a + b = Dec(Enc(a) * Enc(b)).